# Separate public subnets for VPN access in my AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb, terraform

I'm setting up an AWS VPC, and have carved it up into public, cache, persistence and compute subnets. 
I plan on separating resources in the following way:

- Public: ELB and VPN network association
- Cache: ElastiCache
- Persistence: RDS
- Compute: EC2 instances

In order to enable local development, I have created an AWS Client VPN endpoint and associated it with **one** of my public subnets.

After allowing egress from public subnets to the persistence subnets and ingress to persistence from public, and updating the RDS security group I am able to connect to the database through the VPN.

This works, but I wonder if it would be best to create a VPN only subnet to further compartmentalize resources. Would this be overkill since ELB is the only other resource in the public subnets?

I would appreciate any advice and if there's another way of achieving this goal, I'm still flexible. I considered assigning a security group to the VPN network association, but this cannot be managed by Terraform.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest even your setup is an overkill. In general just *Public* and *Private* subnets across 2 or 3 availability zones are enough.

Access control is best done through *Security Groups* attached to resources, with ingress rules referencing *other Security Groups*, not other subnet CIDRs or IP ranges. For example *RDS SG* may only allow inbound access from your *EC2 SG*, regardless of what IPs the EC2 instances have or in which subnet they are.

That way you can compartmentalise individual resources to Security Groups and control traffic between the groups without slicing your network to heaps of tiny subnets.

Hope that helps :)